# Анимация увеличение числа

Tags: jquery, анимация, javascript

Есть ли в jquery, или написанная на стандартном js функция проигрывания увеличение числа? Например:

Увеличение значения от 1% до 80%, быстро проиграв все значения промежуточные значения (2,3,4...)?

Comment: Это как - "*в jquery ... на стандартном js*"? Я думаю, что там всё написано "*на стандартном js*". Но это пол беды, а что значит "проигрывания увеличение числа" или, тем более, "анимация увеличение числа"? Вам нужено что-то [вроде счетчика][1]?

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/6wpXy/

Comment: зачем таймер то глобальным(а не глобальным, но непонятно зачем его объявлять null) сделали ? надо `end = 80,` вместо `end = 80;` http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6wpXy/2/

Comment: https://t.me/feenproject/16
Можешь глянуть здесь, как вариант

Answer (score 10):

http://jsfiddle.net/8Sdpy/ — только ради спортивного интереса

```
jQuery(function ($)
    // Добавляем hook "number"
    $.Tween.propHooks.number = {
        get: function ( tween ){
            var num = tween.elem.innerHTML.replace(/^[^\d-]+/, '');
            return  parseFloat(num) || 0;
        },

        set: function( tween ) {
            var opts = tween.options;
            tween.elem.innerHTML = (opts.prefix || '')
              + tween.now.toFixed(opts.fixed || 0)
              + (opts.postfix || '');
          }
    };

    // Используем
    $('#target')
       .html('1%')
       .animate({ number: 80 }, { duration: 'slow', postfix: '%', fixed: 2 });
});
```

Или совсем просто — http://jsfiddle.net/QGY28/

```
$('#num').animate({ num: 90 - 3/* - начало */ }, {
    duration: 5000,
    step: function (num){
        this.innerHTML = (num + 3).toFixed(2) + '%'
    }
});
```

Comment: при этом разделитель между числами "." а как изменить его на запятую?